# How to set the column of the last row of each group to the previous row's column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`, that has columns `id`, `time`, `start_quantity`, `end_quantity`. For each `id` and `time`, the `start_quantity` is equal to the `end_quantity` at the previous time.

Here's an example:

```
id   time       start_quantity      end_quantity
0    1          0                   10
0    2          10                  15
.....
23   1          55                  87       
23   2          87                  90
.....
```

There's a degenerate case in `df`, where the last row of each `id` (note that dataframe is pregrouped by `id` and within each `id` group its sorted in ascending order based on `time`), has an incorrect `start_quantity`. The last row for each `id` is always `time = 10`.

For each of these rows, I would like to make the correction, but when I tried

```
df.loc[df[df.time == 10], "start_quantity"] = df.loc[df[df.time == 9], "end_quantity"]
```

It makes the `start_quantity` for those rows `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

Shift the values in the end quantity per id, then use boolean indexing with `loc` to update the values where `time == 10`

```
s = df.groupby('id')['end_quantity'].shift()
df.loc[df['time'] == 10, 'start_quantity'] = s
```

Alternative approach:

```
df.loc[df['time'] == 10, 'start_quantity'] = df.loc[df['time'] == 9, 'end_quantity'].tolist()
```

Comment: Do you know what the issue was with the approach in the OP?

Comment: @roulette01 The indexing in OP is invalid since `df[df.time == 10]` will return a filtered dataframe instead of boolean series/mask also while doing the assignment the indices needs to match hence we have to remove the index information from RHS using `.tolist()`